# Como pegar o valor de input text com AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando pegar o valor de um input e salvá-lo numa variável para que eu possa usar o resultado como um valor no `LIKE`, de uma consulta do `sqlite`. Só que me deparei com um pequeno problema: quando tento pegar o valor do input o resultado que vem é `undefined`, mas se eu usar um controller na div que envolve o input, aí sim vem o resultado correto. Estou tentando pegar esse valor com a função dentro do controller do template.

Então me surgiu a seguinte dúvida: é possível que eu pegue o valor do input com alguma função que esteja dentro do controller desse template ou vou ter que criar outro controller só pra pegar o valor do input? E se tiver que criar outro controller, como posso pegar e usá-lo na consulta `SQL`?

**Edited**

Vou colocar aqui o código do meu controller e o HTML, pode ser que fique mais fácil de entender:

```js
myApp.controller("ServicesCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
  
  var result = '';

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $scope.myClick = function() {
      result = $scope.searchkey;
      console.log(result);
    };

    var query = "SELECT serviceName FROM tblServices WHERE serviceName LIKE '%"+ result +"%' ";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
      if(res.rows.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
          console.log(res.rows.item(i).serviceName);
        }
      }
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." name="key" autocorrect="off" ng-model="searchkey">
  </label>
  <button class="button" ng-click="myClick()">Buscar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A sua função `myClick` não exibe nada no console?

Comment: Retorna `undefined`. Só pega o valor correto se o controller estiver na div e não no template, que é como estou usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi pq no seu controller está fazendo o select fora da função do click, imagino que queira já fazer o select assim que carregar o ionic, mas a função não precisa estar dentro do ready.

No controller eu sempre seto o valor default que vou usar nas variaveis do scope, assim como fez com a result

```
myApp.controller("ServicesCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPlatform,     $cordovaSQLite) {

  var result = '';
  $scope.searchkey = '';

  $scope.myClick = function() {
      result = $scope.searchkey;
      console.log(result);
  };

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    //desta forma chama o select com o result = '' assim que carregar o ionic
    var query = "SELECT serviceName FROM tblServices WHERE serviceName LIKE '%"+ result +"%' ";
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
      if(res.rows.length > 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
          console.log(res.rows.item(i).serviceName);
        }
      }
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });

});
```

Se não resolver o problema tem uma forma de passar o valor do input como parâmetro na função:

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
       <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." name="key" autocorrect="off" ng-model="searchkey">
    </label>
    <button class="button" ng-click="myClick(searchkey)">Buscar</button>
</div>
```

Nesta caso basta arrumar a sua função myClick para receber o parametro:

```
$scope.myClick = function(search) {
    result = search;
    console.log(result);
};
```

Comment: Funcionou tudo certinho! Muito obrigado, André. Eu até cheguei a tentar passar o valor como parâmetro, mas também não estava dando certo, acho que eu estava deixando passar alguma coisa despercebido.